# How to filter everything from an Entity using Entity Framework

Tags: linq, entity-framework, orm, entity

I'm using VS2010, VB.NET and Entity Framework.

I have a textbox in my application where you can search a person by texting his name, his identification number or his last name. And obviously I have a table in Data Base called PERSON, how can I do to retrieve all persons from database that match with the search.

For example I have this two people in my database:

**Person 1.**
Name: Samantha
Last Name: Randf
ID: 702020406

**Person 2**
Name: Eric
Last Name: Salas
ID: 405670233

And if a person texts in the search text field the letter **"s"** ...both person should be retrieve from database because there is a coincidence with person 1 in the name and with person 2 in the last name.
It's a global search, any idea?

Answer (score 0):

```
context.Persons.Where(p => p.Name.Contains("s") || p.LastName.Contains("s"))
```

Comment: @Salas. No problem I was glad to help. Don't forget to accept an answer if you got one. Have a good day

Answer (score 0):

You can use Contains() method to match the search string. The following example will return people whose name contains 's' at any place in their first name or last name.

```
context.Persons.Where(p => p.Name.ToLower().Contains("s") || p.LastName.ToLower().Contains("s"));
```

Alternatively, you can use standard SQL statement with LIKE operator and execute it with `context.ExecuteStoreQuery()` function.